# How can I remove duplicates where some duplicates have to be excluded from the removal based on data in a separate table?

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'm using SQL 2008 trying to remove duplicates for a somewhat unique situation and I haven't been able to figure it out or find a solution.

I have one table (CUST_REF) that has a CUST_ID column that is a foreign key from table (CUST_MAST).  CUST_REF is the table with the duplicates that I am concerned with.  There are duplicate records in CUST_REF as seen in the example below for IDs 1 & 2 and 3 & 4 (not including the ID column).  Although IDs 3 & 4 are duplicates in that table, if we look up their CUST_ID in CUST_MAST we see they reference different CUST_NO values, so those duplicate records are fine and I don't want to remove either of them.

```
CUST_REF
ID   CUST_ID   DEPT   DIV   ATT_NAME   ATT_VALUE      
 1        11     01    01       PASS       12345
 2        12     01    01       PASS       12345
 3        15     02    21       PASS       98765
 4        16     02    21       PASS       98765
 5        23     10    11       PASS       98765

CUST_MAST
CUST_ID   CUST_NO
     11       310
     12       310
     15       242
     16       911
     23       750
```

I am using a `Group By DEPT, DIV, ATT_NAME Having Count > 1` to find the duplicates in CUST_REF but I don't know how to filter the duplicates using CUST_NO from the other table.   Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A question about your sample data. In CUST_MAST should CUST_!D 17 actually be 16? Also, what RDBMS ar eyou using at is may affect the solution.

Comment: Yes, I changed that ID.  I'm using MSSQL 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables on CUST_ID and then add CUST_ID to the your Group By. This will include the second table before grouping and avoid the "false" duplicates.